# Confused about K&R c explanation on type conversions

Tags: c

The book says the following on page 45:

> Since an argument of a function call is an expression, type conversions also take place when arguments are passed to functions. In the absence of a function prototype, `char` and `short` become `int`, and `float` becomes `double`. This is why we have declared function arguments to be `int` and `double` even when the function is called with `char` and `float`.

I don't understand what the last sentence there is saying. Can someone lead me in the right direction?

Comment: This no longer applies, as function prototypes are mandatory, right?

Comment: @FiddlingBits Prototypes are not mandatory in C

Comment: Can you put that example on site

Comment: Declarations are mandatory but declarations need not be prototypes.

Comment: This comment really does only apply historically. Nothing is lost by ignoring it.

Comment: function prototypes are definitely not mandatory in K&R C.  Even the ansi c way to declare function prototypes is not mandatory in C.

Answer (score 3):

We can see that happen here. According to [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/), this is the declaration of `printf()`:

```
int printf(const char * format, ...);
```

The `...` means this function can take an unknown number of parameters of unspecified types, and because it is unspecified, the standardization of numeric types to `int` and `double` happens to all `printf()` parameters except the first, that was specified.

Example:

```
char x = 10;
short y = 100;
int z = 1000;
printf("Values of char is %d, short is %d, and int is %d", x, y, z);
```

All those integer types are automatically recasted to `int` when passed to `printf()`. We can see that as `%d` works for all of them.

Note that types bigger than `double` and `int` are not converted, such as `long int`, `long double`, `long long` etc. Those types are 64-bits.

Comment: `z` is not converted!

Comment: No; `z` is not converted because it is `long` which is not a type shorter than `int`.  Only types shorter than `int` (three flavours of `char` and two flavours of `short` are converted to `int`; only `float` is converted to `double`.  Neither `long` nor `long double` is converted.  (And `int z;` is not converted to `int` either because it is already `int`, but that doesn't change the value.)

Comment: Usually `long` and `int` are the same size, but I see your point. 64-bit variables are still passed as 64-bit.

Comment: The only times `long` and `int` are the same size are if you program on Windows or 32-bit platforms.  These days, I seldom program for either.  And sloppiness in the types passed to `printf()` and specified in the format string can cause a lot of pain when migrating between 32-bit and 64-bit platforms.

Comment: You cannot assume long and int will be the same size. I don't know where you got that idea

Comment: I've been programming 32-bits for over a decade, I'm still getting used to the peculiarities of 64-bit. Sometimes I forget `long` can have a whole new meaning when compiling in this platform.

Comment: Please, don't use printf() in c++, it's not recommended to use it, as it doesn't get parameter passing checks.  Even this is not a c++ related question.  The author is asking for K&R behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a prototype for a function in C (ansi C, as original K&R specification didn't define parameters this way) you declare a formal parameter as having a type.  When you match it in an actual expression, two things can happen:

1. The formal parameter and the actual expression are the same type.  In this case, every thing is fine and the expression value is used to initialize the parameter prior to call the function.
2. The formal parameter and the actual expression are not the same type.  In that case, the compiler tries to do automatic type conversion if possible from the type of the actual expression to the formal parameter type.

In case no prototype is found, the rules you put above mandate, so chars and shorts get promoted to int values, and al the floating type values get promoted to double.

The last phrase in your quoted paragraph tells you that in some example (not shown) that types are being used for formal parameters to make sure actual expressions get converted to the types of formal parameters.

Comment: In the second case, where no prototype is found: does that mean that the arguments get re-casted to the formal parameter types upon function invocation, or do they simply get reinterpreted as such (i.e. type punning), which could be wrong? Example: suppose you have the function `int foo(double)`, but you don't declare this function (ANSI C allows this) in a translation unit where the call `foo(123ull)` occurs. Does this mean that the bit representation of `123ull` will simply get re-interpreted as a `double` in the function's body, or will a cast to `double` happen when `foo` is invoked?

Comment: Nope, when no prototype is found you normally get a warning about some undefined function is being used without declaration and the data is just passed to the function with the cited conversion.  That's the _old C way_ of proceeding, and is maintained so legacy code can still compile.  As K&R says in your cite, `char` and `short` are converted to `int`, and `float` is converted to `double` (but this has not always been like this, you are citing from 2nd edition K&R)